# Facing issue during hot deploy of kar file

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, osgi, blueprint-osgi

My kar file contains the following bundles:

a)**common-bundle**(contains hibernate as the JPA provider)

b)**client-bundle**(accesses the entityManagerFactory present inside common-bundle and execute business logic)

I've a strange problem while executing hot deploy of kar file on karaf container.

If I try to do a normal deploy(i.e. by stopping the karaf container,putting the kar file into deploy folder and re-starting karaf container),both the bundles get up and running without any problem.

However,when I try to hot deploy the kar file on karaf container,it throws me the following exception:

> Dec 06 13:50:50 INFO 141 HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
>           name: MyModelClass
>           ...]
>   Dec 06 13:50:51 INFO 141 HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
>   Dec 06 13:50:51 ERROR 187 The DataSource osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=jdbc/ds) required by bundle common-bundle/0.0.1.SNAPSHOT could not be found.
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/"(osgi.jndi.service.name=jdbc/ds)"
>           at org.apache.aries.jndi.url.ServiceRegistryContext.lookup(ServiceRegistryContext.java:113)[66:org.apache.aries.jndi.url:1.1.0]
>           at org.apache.aries.jndi.url.ServiceRegistryContext.lookup(ServiceRegistryContext.java:138)[66:org.apache.aries.jndi.url:1.1.0]
>           at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)[64:org.apache.aries.jndi.core:1.0.2]
>           at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)[:1.8.0_141]
>           at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.unit.impl.JndiDataSource.getDs(JndiDataSource.java:66)[187:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:1.0.4]
>           at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.unit.impl.DelayedLookupDataSource.getConnection(DelayedLookupDataSource.java:36)[187:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:1.0.4]
>           at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:70)[213:org.hibernate.entitymanager:4.2.21.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:242)[212:org.hibernate.core:4.2.21.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:117)[212:org.hibernate.core:4.2.21.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:85)[212:org.hibernate.core:4.2.21.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:184)[212:org.hibernate.core:4.2.21.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:156)[212:org.hibernate.core:4.2.21.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1827)[212:org.hibernate.core:4.2.21.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1785)[212:org.hibernate.core:4.2.21.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)[213:org.hibernate.entitymanager:4.2.21.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)[213:org.hibernate.entitymanager:4.2.21.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.osgi.OsgiPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(OsgiPersistenceProvider.java:99)[214:org.hibernate.osgi:4.2.21.Final]
>           at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.EntityManagerFactoryManager.createEntityManagerFactories(EntityManagerFactoryManager.java:432)[187:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:1.0.4]
>           at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.EntityManagerFactoryManager.registerEntityManagerFactories(EntityManagerFactoryManager.java:292)[187:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:1.0.4]
>           at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.EntityManagerFactoryManager.access$000(EntityManagerFactoryManager.java:74)[187:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:1.0.4]
>           at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.EntityManagerFactoryManager$1.call(EntityManagerFactoryManager.java:203)[187:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:1.0.4]
>           at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.EntityManagerFactoryManager$1.call(EntityManagerFactoryManager.java:199)[187:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:1.0.4]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)[:1.8.0_141]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)[:1.8.0_141]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)[:1.8.0_141]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)[:1.8.0_141]
>   Dec 06 13:50:51 WARN 187 Error creating EntityManagerFactory
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: The DataSource osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=jdbc/ds) required by bundle common-bundle/0.0.1.SNAPSHOT could not be found.
>           at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.unit.impl.JndiDataSource.getDs(JndiDataSource.java:87)[187:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:1.0.4]
>           at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.unit.impl.DelayedLookupDataSource.getConnection(DelayedLookupDataSource.java:36)[187:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:1.0.4]
>           at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:70)[213:org.hibernate.entitymanager:4.2.21.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:242)[212:org.hibernate.core:4.2.21.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:117)[212:org.hibernate.core:4.2.21.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:85)[212:org.hibernate.core:4.2.21.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:184)[212:org.hibernate.core:4.2.21.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:156)[212:org.hibernate.core:4.2.21.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1827)[212:org.hibernate.core:4.2.21.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1785)[212:org.hibernate.core:4.2.21.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)[213:org.hibernate.entitymanager:4.2.21.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)[213:org.hibernate.entitymanager:4.2.21.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.osgi.OsgiPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(OsgiPersistenceProvider.java:99)[214:org.hibernate.osgi:4.2.21.Final]
>           at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.EntityManagerFactoryManager.createEntityManagerFactories(EntityManagerFactoryManager.java:432)[187:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:1.0.4]
>           at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.EntityManagerFactoryManager.registerEntityManagerFactories(EntityManagerFactoryManager.java:292)[187:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:1.0.4]
>           at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.EntityManagerFactoryManager.access$000(EntityManagerFactoryManager.java:74)[187:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:1.0.4]
>           at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.EntityManagerFactoryManager$1.call(EntityManagerFactoryManager.java:203)[187:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:1.0.4]
>           at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.EntityManagerFactoryManager$1.call(EntityManagerFactoryManager.java:199)[187:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:1.0.4]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)[:1.8.0_141]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)[:1.8.0_141]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)[:1.8.0_141]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)[:1.8.0_141]
>   Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/"(osgi.jndi.service.name=jdbc/ds)"
>           at org.apache.aries.jndi.url.ServiceRegistryContext.lookup(ServiceRegistryContext.java:113)[66:org.apache.aries.jndi.url:1.1.0]
>           at org.apache.aries.jndi.url.ServiceRegistryContext.lookup(ServiceRegistryContext.java:138)[66:org.apache.aries.jndi.url:1.1.0]
>           at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)[64:org.apache.aries.jndi.core:1.0.2]
>           at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)[:1.8.0_141]
>           at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.unit.impl.JndiDataSource.getDs(JndiDataSource.java:66)[187:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:1.0.4]
>           ... 21 more
>   Dec 06 13:50:51 INFO 141 HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
>           name: MyModelClass
>           ...]
>   Dec 06 13:50:52 INFO 141 HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
>   Dec 06 13:50:55 INFO 141 HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
>   Dec 06 13:50:55 INFO 141 HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
>   Dec 06 13:50:55 INFO 141 HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
>   Dec 06 13:50:56 WARN 141 HHH000008: JTASessionContext being used with JDBCTransactionFactory; auto-flush will not operate correctly with getCurrentSession()

Following are the most important contents of the bundles:

**common-bundle:**

**Persistence.xml:**

```
<persistence version="2.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

<persistence-unit name="my-persistent-unit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=jdbc/ds)</non-jta-data-source>
    <class>MyModelClass</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
</persistence-unit>
```

**blueprint.xml:**

```
<cm:property-placeholder persistent-id='my-persistent-id'
                         update-strategy='reload'
                         placeholder-prefix="${"
                         placeholder-suffix="}">
    <cm:default-properties>
        <cm:property name="driver" value="undefined"/>
        <cm:property name="url" value="undefined"/>
        <cm:property name="username" value="undefined"/>
        <cm:property name="password" value="undefined"/>
    </cm:default-properties>
</cm:property-placeholder>

<jasypt:property-placeholder encryptor-ref="encryptor"/>
<reference id="encryptor" interface="org.jasypt.encryption.StringEncryptor" availability="mandatory"/>

<bean id='myDs'
      class="CustomConnection">
    <property name="connectionFactoryClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"/>
    <property name="URL" value="${url}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
    <property name="validateConnectionOnBorrow" value="true"/>
</bean>

<service ref='myDs' interface='javax.sql.DataSource'>
    <service-properties>
        <entry key='osgi.jndi.service.name' value='jdbc/ds'/>
    </service-properties>
</service>
```

**client-bundle:**

**blueprint.xml**

```
<bean id="myController"
      class="MyController">
    <argument ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
<reference id="entityManagerFactory"
           interface="javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory"
           filter="(osgi.unit.name=my-persistent-unit)"
           availability="mandatory"/>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently every bundle is using a datasource but no one is creating it.

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/"(osgi.jndi.service.name=jdbc/ds)"

You need to create this datasource, for example by dropping a simple XML file into deploy dir:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/yourdb"/>
        <property name="username" value="XXX"/>
        <property name="password" value="XXX"/>
    </bean>

    <service interface="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="dataSource">
        <service-properties>
            <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/ds"/>
        </service-properties>
    </service>
</blueprint>
```

You will need **jdbc** and **jndi** features installed.